# How to show individual and combined categories in the same boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I want to have a plot that shows an additional boxplot below the boxplots of 9 categories to 2 timepoints.

What I've already done:

Create a pandas df.

```
data = {'Category':  ['waschen','anziehen','lesen', 'putzen', 'zahnpflege', 'essen', 'hobby', 'schlafen', 'spazieren', 'waschen',
                      'anziehen','lesen', 'putzen', 'zahnpflege', 'essen', 'hobby', 'schlafen', 'spazieren'],
        'T1': ['1', '6', '5','8', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '3', '2', '1', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1'],
         'T2':['3', '7', '7','9', '8', '10', '8', '9', '3', '10', '9', '5', '3', '8', '9', '6', '7', '5']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Create a boxplot and order the categories according to my preferences.

```
sns.boxplot(y='Category', x='value', hue='variable', 
            data=df.melt(id_vars='Category', var_name='variable', value_name='value'),
           palette='Blues',
           order=['waschen', 'anziehen', 'zahnpflege', 'putzen', 'schlafen', 'essen', 'lesen', 'hobby', 'spazieren'])
plt.show()
```

[image: df]

Plot a boxplot of the 2 timepoints overall the categories.

```
sns.boxplot(x= 'value', y='variable',
            data=df.melt(var_name='variable', value_name='value'),
            palette='Reds')
```

[image: df_gesamt]

Now I want these 2 plots in one plot. Because I want to show the overall values in relation to the individual category values (x-axis is the same).
Is it possible with seaborn or should I use matplotlib subplots?

My idea was to create a figure with 2 axes and I tried this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1) sns.boxplot((data=df_gesamt,
orient='h'), ax=axes[0,0])
```

But got an error:

```
Input In [13]
    sns.boxplot((data=df_gesamt, orient='h'), ax=axes[0,0])
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: For your second plot, you also need `id_vars='Category'`, to prevent the categories be included in the variables. So `sns.boxplot(x='value', y='variable', data=df.melt(id_vars='Category', var_name='variable', value_name='value'), palette='Reds')`

Answer (score 1):

After converting the columns to numeric, you can use the following tricks to combine both plots:

- add an extra label in `order` to put the overall boxplots
- use a dummy `y` repeating that label as many times as there are rows in the long dataframe

Optionally, you can combine the legend.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = {'Category': ['waschen', 'anziehen', 'lesen', 'putzen', 'zahnpflege', 'essen', 'hobby', 'schlafen', 'spazieren',
                     'waschen', 'anziehen', 'lesen', 'putzen', 'zahnpflege', 'essen', 'hobby', 'schlafen', 'spazieren'],
        'T1': ['1', '6', '5', '8', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '3', '2', '1', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1'],
        'T2': ['3', '7', '7', '9', '8', '10', '8', '9', '3', '10', '9', '5', '3', '8', '9', '6', '7', '5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['T1'] = df['T1'].astype(float)
df['T2'] = df['T2'].astype(float)

together_val = '--zusammen--'
order = ['waschen', 'anziehen', 'zahnpflege', 'putzen', 'schlafen', 'essen', 'lesen', 'hobby',
         'spazieren'] + [together_val]

df_long = df.melt(id_vars='Category', var_name='variable', value_name='value')
ax = sns.boxplot(y='Category', x='value', hue='variable',
                 data=df_long,
                 palette='Blues',
                 order=order)
sns.boxplot(y=[together_val] * len(df_long), x='value', hue='variable',
            data=df_long,
            palette='Reds',
            order=order,
            ax=ax)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(handles=[tuple(handles[i::2]) for i in range(len(handles) // 2)], labels=labels[:2],
          loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.01), handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=2)})
ax.set_xlabel('')  # optionally remove the x label
ax.set_ylabel('')
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: individual and combined box plots]

Answer (score 0):

change columns type, its work for me:

```
df.T1 = df.T1.astype(int)
df.T2 = df.T2.astype(int)
sns.boxplot(y='Category', x='value', hue='variable', 
            data=df.melt(id_vars='Category', var_name='variable', value_name='value'),
           palette='Blues',
           order=['waschen', 'anziehen', 'zahnpflege', 'putzen', 'schlafen', 'essen', 'lesen', 'hobby', 'spazieren'])
```

Answer (score 0):

- As demonstrated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67678064/7758804), use [`pandas.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a `combined` DataFrame where the `'Category'` and `'Observation'` column values are uniquely named.
- `combined` is concatenated to the long form of the the original data with [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), and plotted with `seaborn`.
- **Tested in `python 3.11`, `pandas 1.5.3`, `matplotlib 3.7.0`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

### Manage the Data

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# beginning with the sample data in the OP
data = {'Category': ['waschen', 'anziehen', 'lesen', 'putzen', 'zahnpflege', 'essen', 'hobby', 'schlafen', 'spazieren', 'waschen', 'anziehen', 'lesen', 'putzen', 'zahnpflege', 'essen', 'hobby', 'schlafen', 'spazieren'],
        'T1': ['1', '6', '5', '8', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1', '7', '3', '2', '1', '4', '7', '5', '7', '1'],
        'T2': ['3', '7', '7', '9', '8', '10', '8', '9', '3', '10', '9', '5', '3', '8', '9', '6', '7', '5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert the dataframe to a long form
df = df.melt(id_vars='Category', var_name='Observation', value_name='Value')

# convert the Value column to int or float as needed
df.Value = df.Value.astype(int)

# create the Category plot order
new_cat = 'Combined'
order = ['waschen', 'anziehen', 'zahnpflege', 'putzen', 'schlafen', 'essen', 'lesen', 'hobby', 'spazieren'] + [new_cat]

# create a new dataframe with Category as Combined, and the Observation value is updated "if desired"
combined = df.assign(Category=new_cat, Observation=lambda x: x['Observation'] + ' - ' + x['Category'])
# combined = df.assign(Category=new_cat)  # without updating Observation

# concat the two dataframes
combined = pd.concat([df, combined], ignore_index=True)
```

### Plot a seaborn [axes-level plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.boxplot(data=combined, y='Category', x='Value', hue='Observation', order=order, ax=ax)
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
sns.boxplot(data=combined, y='Category', x='Value', hue='Observation', order=order, ax=ax)
# set the 'Combined' ytick label to as red
ax.get_ymajorticklabels()[-1].set_color('red')
sns.move_legend(ax, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc='upper left', frameon=False)
```

[image]

### Plot a seaborn [figure-level plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)

```py
g = sns.catplot(data=combined, kind='box', y='Category', x='Value', hue='Observation', order=order, height=7, aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

```py
g = sns.catplot(data=combined, kind='box', y='Category', x='Value', hue='Observation', order=order, height=7, aspect=1.5)
# get the axes from the FacetGrid
ax1 = g.axes.flat[0]
# set the 'Combined' ytick label to as red
ax1.get_ymajorticklabels()[-1].set_color('red')
```

[image]